# Is this comma splice?

Tags: punctuation, commas, comma-splices

> Running outdoors burns about five percent more calories than running on a tread mill, in part because there is greater wind resistance outdoors.

Apparently this is correct and there is no comma splice; could someone please explain why? Isn't the part after the comma an independent clause?

Comment: General Reference. Anyone who knows what a "comma splice" is should realise this isn't an example. In nearly all cases, a comma splice can be avoided by substituting a full stop; that clearly doesn't work in OP's example, ***because** it isn't a comma splice*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The words following the comma constitute a dependent clause, not an independent one. An independent clause must be able to stand alone without being subordinate to another clause. The clause *in part because there is greater wind resistance outdoors* has no meaning on its own. It is an adverbial clause of reason, explaining the claim made in the main clause.